# Magento2: OnePageCheckout skip selection of shipping method

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

In my project store I have a fixed rate for shipping anywhere (**flatrate**) but during the checkout process I still have to make the **ajax call** to select the shipping method.
Is there a way to skip this?
So the shipping method is selected on checkout preperation?

I only found a way to hide the select shipping method form but thats more of a workaround.

Im currently running `Magento CE 2.2.4`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, hiding is the only option.

But it is possible for you to hide it via jquery (yeah kind of a workaround as well i know, but at least a dynamic one).

You could hide it, if you only have one shipping option, and as soon as you've got 2 you unhide it.

This way you've got a more dynamic solution.